# Call a function from another class in C#

Tags: c#, draw, shapes

I am dealing with a new project. I have a class to draw Rectangles to windows form. I want to embed this class to another class. Code's below;

Main Code will call the shape code;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using sekilciz_uygulama;



namespace xml_test_v1

{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();

        xDoc.Load("c:\\sw_xml_test_4.xml");
        int rad=0;
        string giris_text = Console.ReadLine().ToString();

        Console.WriteLine(giris_text);
            foreach(XmlNode node in xDoc.SelectNodes("network/switch"))



            {

                string ip_adress =      node.SelectSingleNode("ip_adress").InnerText.ToString();

                Console.WriteLine(ip_adress);

                if (ip_adress.Contains(giris_text))

                {
                   // call for shape code!!!
                }


                }}}}
```

Code for Creating Shapes;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;

namespace sekilciz_uygulama
{
public class Sekilciz
{

    public Rectangle[] skare;

    private SolidBrush firca;
    private int x,y, genislik, yukseklik;

    public Sekilciz()

    {
      skare = new Rectangle[5];
        firca = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);

        x = 500;
        y = 200;
        genislik= 100;

        yukseklik =100;


        for(int i=0; i< skare.Length;i++)

        {
             skare[i] = new Rectangle(x,y,genislik,yukseklik);

            x-=150;
        }
    }

    public void kareciz(Graphics duzlem)

    {
        foreach(Rectangle rec in skare)

        {
            duzlem.FillRectangle(firca,rec);
        }
    }
    }
```

}

Comment: why you want to embed when you are already referring the namespace sekilciz_uygulama

Comment: cause i want to draw shapes :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// "this" is  your windows form, or control like button
var myGraphic = this.CreateGraphics();
var sekilciz = new Sekilciz(myGraphic);
sekilciz.kareciz();
```

But you have too many processing going on in your constructor. It is better to move that code in some other method in the same class.

Look here to complete sample on drawing on windows form:
**[The Basics of Drawing Graphics onto Windows Forms](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/TheButler/the-basics-of-drawing-graphics-onto-windows-forms/)**

Comment: sekilciz.kareciz() return an error: "No overload for method 'kareciz' takes 0 argument"

Comment: Yes, you must pass a Graphic object instance to kareciz method, because the method signature iz defined as: public void kareciz(Graphics duzlem)

Comment: i understand. But how can i do that?

Comment: I add some reference but gettin this error: Error 1 'xml_test_v1.Program' does not contain a definition for 'CreateGraphics' and no extension method 'CreateGraphics' accepting a first argument of type 'xml_test_v1.Program' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\**\Program_3.cs 94 64 xml_test_v1.0

Comment: You don't need the "CreateGraphics()"-Method... Please don't mix two solutions and stick with the one you prefer...

Answer (score 0):

```
var sekilciz = new Sekilciz();
sekilciz.kareciz(null);
```

You need to pass a parameter to your method `kareciz`

Comment: Error 1 The type 'System.Drawing.Graphics' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. C:\**\Program_3.cs 86 43 xml_test_v1.0

Comment: The error says what you need to do: `You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Drawing` Right click on "References" and search for "System.Drawing" in the list.